# Does a good equivalent of "pitch" not exist?

Tags: translation

I've been wondering if there is a good Chinese equivalent of the word pitch. Pitch is short for [sales pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sales_presentation) and it is another term for a sales presentation (presentation, another word without a good Chinese equivalent), basically it:

> is a line of talk that attempts to persuade someone or something, with a planned sales presentation strategy of a product or service designed to initiate and close a sale of the product or service.

There is also a Wiki page for filmmaking, [pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(filmmaking)). Where it talks about people selling there idea of film or TV.

It isn't that there isn't an equivalent word, it is just that usually the English word becomes the default. There is a question on Zhihu entitled: [投售或推介 (Pitch) 时你都有哪些诀窍？](https://www.zhihu.com/question/27154794), where we see two Chinese words 投售 and 推介, but in the description of the question it goes on to say:

> 欢迎来说说自己 pitch 时的一些小窍门。

The highest upvoted answer is also filled with English:

> Pitch的确是有一些Dos and Don'ts。我来到这个问题主要是刚刚休息的时候看了一个Pitch集锦，特别想找人聊聊——一搜知乎，果然有。

Does a good equivalent of "pitch" not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Pitch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch)
>
> 3a: to present or advertise especially in a high-pressure way : plug, promote
>
> 3b: to attempt to persuade especially with a sales pitch
>
> In these cases, 'pitch' means "**推銷**" E.g. "推銷某主張" (to pitch an idea); "推銷某產品" (to pitch  a product)

~

> 3c : to present (a movie or program idea) for consideration (as by a TV producer)
>
> In this case, 'pitch' means "**推薦**" or **提議**  E.g. "推薦某劇本" / "提議某劇本" (to pitch a script)

- 推銷 - to promote --> pitch
- 推薦 - to recommend --> pitch
- 提議 - to proposal --> pitch

Typically, a pitch is an oral **presentation**

Pitch = (現場)推銷; (現場)推薦